# How to return value from C macro?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I was trying to implement the `sizeof()` operator, and wanted the macro to return the result like the one provided by C lang.

I implemented it using gcc construct '()' like:

```
#define SIZEOF(type)\   
({\ 
 int result;\
 type *p = 0;\
 result = (char*)(p+1)-(char*)p;\
 result;\
})
```

And used it like this:

```
x = SIZEOF(double);
```

Is there any way to do it without using gcc construct and returning value from that?

The best i can think of is pass another parameter to macro and store result in that like:

```
#define SIZEOF(type,result)\
 do{\
   type *p = 0;\
   result = (char*)(p+1)-(char*)p;\
 }while(0)
```

I know that I can replace this macro with inline function which will do the work but was looking for something in macro context. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: sizeof is not provided by C lib.

Comment: have you considered comma operator?

Comment: Thanks @tristan i have changed it to lang construct.

Comment: @tristan i tried comma operator, that also didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define SIZEOF(type) (long int) (((type*)0) + 1)
```

Comment: How to implement an inline function which takes a _data type_ as parameter?

Comment: @thisisdog:your code solves the problem..but is there any way to write return in macro what i have stated in problem..like if u have multiple statement in macro?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think as soon as you introduce scope you have a problem - maybe you could do it through clever usage of & and |